# using an observable across different routes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an issue loading data for a sub page, it works fine if I hit the manage products then update the product however if I refresh on the update product it loses the data.

I have a landing page for example: Dashboard which is a sidebar.
When clicking products for example it loads the manage-products page.

in the `manage-products.component.ts` I get the products like this

```
this.products = this.productsService.products;
this.productsService.GetProducts().subscribe();
```

My `products.service.ts`

```
public GetProducts(): Observable<any> {
return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + '/product').map(res => {
  this._productSource.next(res as Product[]);
 });
}
```

When clicking a product it routes to: `product/update/1`
in the `product-update.component.ts`

I filter the data in here using by filtering the observable. If I refresh this page everything is undefined. Should I be getting the product by hitting the API instead of subscribing to the existing observable, if so should I create a new API route that gets the product data by productId or get them all and filter them?

Appreciate any advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From reading the question it is not clear how `product-update.component.ts` gets data it needs to render. My guess is it gets it from `@input()` from parent component.
If so, it has no clue that it needs to update itself when you push refresh.
So my guess that you need a service in child component like so

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSalesItems();
  }

  getSalesItems(): void {
   this.apiService.getSalesItems().subscribe(
     value => {
       this.saleItems = value;        
     },
     error => {
       console.log("Error get req = ", error);
     }
  );
```